# list of current variables in a buffer for Python code

Tags: python, debugging, variables, ipython

I would like to find a way to reproduce the "Workspace" of Matlab or the equivalent "Variables" window of the awesome pudb debugger directly in emacs for python code: it is a window which details the current state of variables, which is particularly useful when debugging or understanding numerical simulation codes.

Here is a screenshot of pudb highlighting the feature I am talking about:

[image: pudb debugger and the window I am trying to implement in emacs]

If it doesn't exist already (which would surprise me a lot), I suppose that it could be possible to automatically create a buffer running the IPython built-in whos function refreshing at each stop of the debugger...

Unfortunately, I am a newbie in Lisp...

Thanks a lot for any kind of support.

Comment: Hopefully this can be achieved through a python language server some day.